# Get Request object in AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

I have a CAS 6.0.1 and I have extended the AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler to match my DB, and everything works fine.

I have a new requirement to basically add sort of a "department" in my login page.  I think that I have 2 options,  either add it as a name/value pair in the URL,  or, as it's a POST, add a hidden field to the form, in addition to the j_username and j_password.

But how would I get that value, either way, in my AuthenticationHandler implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want free-form access to the Request object, you can use:

```java
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)
      RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Or using CAS itself:

```java
HttpServletRequest request = 
      HttpRequestUtils.getHttpServletRequestFromRequestAttributes();
```

This lets you examine parameters such as `department` freely. If you want those parameters to actually be *bound* to the `credential` object that is passed, which contains username/password, etc then you'd need to modify the webflow rather heavily to include those fields into the credential object, change webflow to handle binding, etc. I think the above may seem simpler for the time being.